# Make table whose width is more than the text width to center with `tabularray` in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, tabularray

I make a table whose width is more than the width of the text, so the table is too right on the paper. How should I move it to center?
For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{talltblr}[caption={hello}]{
        colspec={X[c]},width=3cm+\textwidth
    }
    \hline
    hello
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar functionality as `scrextend` offer package `changepage`. With its macro

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{left margin}{right margin}
```

or

```
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{outer margin}
```

locally change text margins. More detail description is in package documentation. In your case your MWE should be changed to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-15mm}{-15mm}
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {hello},
  label = {tab:??}]{hlines, vlines, % that width of table is clearly seen
                 colspec={X[c]}
                }
    Hello world!
\end{talltblr}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between this two packages?

Comment: @Y.zeng, I can't say. I'm not familiar with `scrextend`. As I see from Raffaele Santoro answer, syntax is different. The `changepage` is aware if it is used on odd or even pages, enables simple extend tex area to one side (usual outer) of text area.

Comment: I see the `changepage` is newer than `scrextend` though all of those are so old. But, the newer should be better in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

Use `\centerline{material}`, from your example:

```
\centerline{%
   \begin{talltblr}[caption={hello}]{
           colspec={X[c]},width=3cm+\textwidth
       }
       \hline
       hello
   \end{talltblr}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What package does `\centerline` belong to? What's the meaning of the `\hss`?

Comment: `\centerline` is Plain TeX macro which is defined in LaTeX kernel too. You need not any package. The `\hss` is TeX primitive. Because the LaTeX macro is based on TeX, then this primitive command is ready for LaTeX documents too. It is equivalent to the primitive construction `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil minus 1fil`.

Comment: I tested and found that with and without `\hss` are the same. What is the reason?

Comment: You are right. It was my mistake. `\hss` are needed if plain TeX's `\line` macro is used. `\centerline` macro includes both `\hss` itself.

Answer (score 3):

Put it in a `\makebox` with `[c]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\begin{talltblr}[caption={hello}]{
        colspec={X[c]},width=3cm+\textwidth
    }
    \hline
    hello
\end{talltblr}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** This is only possible with contents that don't cross page borders, e.g. not with `longtblr`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify the margins for your(s) table(s) with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{,showframe,lipsum}% for demo only!
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]\\
    
    \begin{addmargin}[-1.5cm]{-1.5cm}% 1.5cm left, 1.5cm right
                
            \lipsum[2]\\
            
    \end{addmargin}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{addmargin}[1em]{2em}% 1em left, 2em right
        \lipsum[2]\\
        
        \lipsum[3]\\
    \end{addmargin}

    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

You can put your table here:

```
        \begin{addmargin}[-1.5cm]{-1.5cm}% 1.5cm left, 1.5cm right
                    
                \lipsum[2]\\
                
        \end{addmargin}
```

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{adjustwidth}{-15mm}{-15mm}
            \begin{talltblr}[
                caption = {hello},
                label = {tab:hello}]{hlines, colspec={X[l]}
                }
                \lipsum[1-2]
            \end{talltblr}
        \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{table}\\
    See the table \ref{tab:hello}.\\
    \lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I see there is a need to put `begin{add Margin}...\end{addmargin}` in `\begin{table}   \end{table}`. What is the reason?

Comment: @Y.zeng See the EDIT in my answer.